# Closure of sum and multiplication (functional calculus for unbounded linear operators)

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint (unbounded) linear operator in a Hilbert space $H$. Let $E$ be the unique regular resolution of the identity on the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$A= \int_\mathbb{R} t dE(t).$$
We then write
$$f(A)= \int_\mathbb{R} f dE$$ for a measurable function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$
and we have
$$f(A)+ g(A)\subseteq (f+g)(A), \quad f(A)g(A)\subseteq (fg)(A).$$
Note that the right hand sides $(f+g)(A)$ and $(fg)(A)$ are closed operators, so this begs the questions:

Is $(f+g)(A)$ the closure of $f(A)+g(A)$? Similarly, is $(fg)(A)$ the closure of $f(A)g(A)$? How to prove this?

I learnt this stuff from chapter 13 in Rudin's functional analysis book, so an answer that uses tools from this chapter is highly appreciated! Of course, any input is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. In each case, the argument works by localizing the functions to sets where they are bounded. I will only prove it for sums here.

Let $M_n=\{\lambda\in\mathbb R: \lvert f(\lambda)\rvert+\lvert g(\lambda)\rvert\leq n\}$. Clearly, $E(M_n)H\subset D(f(A))\cap D(f(B))$. For $\xi\in D((f+g)(A))$ let $\xi_n=E(M_n)\xi$. As $M_n\nearrow \mathbb R$, we have $\xi_n\to \xi$ in $H$. Moreover,
$$
\lVert (f+g)(A)(\xi-\xi_n)\rVert^2=\lVert (f+g)(A)E(M_n^c)\xi\rVert^2=\int_{\mathbb R}1_{M_n^c}\lvert f(\lambda)+g(\lambda)\rvert^2\,d\langle\xi,E(\lambda)\xi\rangle.
$$
This last integral converges to zero by the dominated convergence theorem. Thus $\xi_n\to \xi$ with respect to the graph norm.

Comment: As a more in-depth reference for these kind of questions, I recommend Schmüdgen's book "Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space".

Comment: Thanks for the answer + reference!

Comment: Why exactly is $E(M_n)H \subseteq D(f(A))$? I have to show something like 
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)^2 d\langle E(M_n)\eta E(\lambda)E(M_n)\eta\rangle <\infty$ which is not immediately clear to me.

Comment: I missed a comma in my above comment in the inner product after the first $\eta$.

Comment: You only have to integrate over $M_n$ (test it for simple functions $f$), and there the integrand is bounded and the measure finite.

Comment: But $M_n$ can be unbounded?

Comment: The set can be unbounded, but $f$ is bounded by $n$ on it.

Comment: Sorry ignore my last comment (now deleted). Was confusing things.

Comment: To justify the use of dominated convergence theorem, you use the inequality $|f+g|^2 \le 2(|f|^2 + |g|^2)$ correct? I.e. the dominating function is $2(|f|^2 + |g|^2)$ (with respect to the total variation measure to make everything work).

Comment: No, $|f+g|^2$ itself is integrable by the definition of $D((f+g)(A))$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, something more general is true. I will treat here the multiplication case, using the same idea as @MaoWao.

**Claim**: Let $E: \mathcal{F}\to B(H)$ be a resolution of the identity where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space. Let $f,g: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be measurable functions. Then
$$\overline{\left(\int fdE\right)\left(\int g dE\right)}= \int (fg)dE.$$

**Proof**: Let $A = \int f dE$ and $B = \int g dE$. Let
$$M_n = \{\omega \in \Omega: |f(\omega)|+|g(\omega)| < n\}.$$
Then $M_n \nearrow \Omega$ so $E(M_n)\nearrow 1_H$ in the strong topology. Note that
$$E(M_n)H \subseteq D(AB) = \{\xi \in D(B): B\xi \in D(A)\}.$$
Indeed, let $\xi \in H$. Then
$$\int_\Omega |g(\omega)|^2dE_{E(M_n)\xi, E(M_n)\xi}(\omega) = \int_{M_n} |g(\omega)|^2 d E_{\xi, \xi}(\omega) \le n^2 \|\xi\|^2  < \infty$$
so $E(M_n)\xi \in D(B)$. On the other hand, using the fact that $B$ and $E(M_n)$ commute, we get
$$\int_\Omega |f(\omega)|^2 dE_{BE(M_n)\xi, BE(M_n)\xi}(\omega)= \int_{M_n} |f(\omega)|^2 dE_{BE(M_n)\xi, BE(M_n)\xi}(\omega) \le n^2 \|BE(M_n)\xi\|^2 < \infty$$
so that $BE(M_n)\xi \in D(A)$. Thus, indeed $E(M_n)H\subseteq D(AB)$.

Next, write $C= \int fg dE$. Let $\xi \in D(C)$. Then
$$\|C(\xi- E(M_n)\xi)\|^2 = \|C E(M_n^c)\xi\|^2 = \int_{M_n^c}|(fg)(\omega)|^2 dE_{\xi, \xi}(\omega)\to 0$$
by the dominated convergence theorem (by assumption, $\int_\Omega |f(\omega)g(\omega)|^2 < \infty$, which acts as the dominating function).

It follows that
$$(E(M_n)\xi, (AB)E(M_n)\xi) = (E(M_n)\xi, CE(M_n)\xi) \to (\xi, C\xi)$$
in $H \oplus H$. Consequently, elements in the graph of $C$ can be norm-approximated by elements in the graph of $AB$. It follows that the closure of the graph of $AB$ is the graph of $C$, which means exactly that $C$ is the closure of $AB$, as desired.

Comment: This looks good. For intuition, I find it sometimes helpful to work with the multiplication operator form of the spectral theorem: Every self-adjoint operator is unitarily equivalent to an operator of the form $D(M_\phi)=\{\xi\in L^2(\mu)\mid \phi f\in L^2(\mu)\}$, $M_\phi \xi=\phi \xi$. In this picture, functional calculus is really just composition of functions, that is, $f(M_\phi)=M_{f\circ\phi}$.